# For MATLAB mirfeatures function I get the valid interpreter syntax error

Tags: matlab, audio-analysis

Following this [manual](https://www.jyu.fi/hytk/fi/laitokset/mutku/en/research/materials/mirtoolbox/manual1-8-1.pdf/view) page 195, I run the `f = mirfeatures(a)`, where `a` is a `miraudio('mysong.wav')` object. Then I want to get the results stored in `f`. However, I get the following error after this command: `f.dynamics.rms{1}`

```
Brace indexing is not supported for variables of this type.
```

and the following warning after this command: `f.dynamics.rms`

```
Warning: Error updating Text.

 String scalar or character vector must have valid interpreter syntax:
RMS energy, E:\Video-Project\Watches\audio_320k_44100_1122002.wav
 
> In defaulterrorcallback (line 12)
In mirscalar/display_figure (line 390)
In mirscalar/display (line 10)
```

I need to mention that when I run `mirrms(a)`. I get no warning. The mentioned commands are on the manual page 195.
Also. `f.dynamics.rms` generates a figure.

Here is the code and the [audio file](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1f04D4IPvH7eif0IhBqVu0qU2jLvXH0JF/view?usp=sharing):

```
a = miraudio('audio_320k_44100_1122002.wav');
f = mirfeatures(a);
f.dynamics.rms;
f.dynamics.rms{1};
```

Comment: Are you sure you have the relevant MATLAB version for which that manual was written and all necessary toolboxes/functions installed and available on your path? Otherwise, do contact the makes of that custom libraby, as they'll have a better idea what's going on than we do.

Comment: If `f.dynamics.rms{1}` gives you that error, then you're expecting it to be a cell array but it isn't. What is the value of `f.dynamics.rms`?

Comment: @Adriaan, the version I use is 1.81. and I am reading the manual for this version.

Comment: @nekomatic, it generates a figure.

Comment: Did you ask the authors of that software and manual? This is not a MATLAB issue, and because you provide no [mre], we cannot reproduce it. Likely scenario is that either you copied a statement wrong from the manual, or something changed in MATLAB since that manual was written.

Comment: @CrisLuengo, How can I access the authors? I will update the question.

Comment: The [toolbox's website](https://www.jyu.fi/hytk/fi/laitokset/mutku/en/research/materials/mirtoolbox) mentions author names, as well as a mailing list. Those are the avenues I'd try first.